# How to resolve Error 404 on Spring boot Webflux WebSocket endpoint

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, websocket, configuration, http-status-code-404

### Edit:
It turns out STOMP needs MVC, and there doesnt seem to be security for the protocol either in WebFlux.
Will try to use RSocket instead of WebSocket

Im trying to use WebSockets with Spring Boot Webflux, but my configuration keeps having issues. I have gone through a lot of articles, tutorials and documentation and tried different versions of configs, but this issue always occurs.

When making a secure HTTP request to the endpoint, 404 is returned.

Here is my configuration:

Version of Spring Boot: 3.1.2
Kotlin version: 1.8.22 (JDK 17)

*WebSocket Config extending WebSocketConfigurer*

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
class WebSocketConfig : WebSocketConfigurer{

    override fun registerWebSocketHandlers(
        registry: WebSocketHandlerRegistry
    ) {
        registry.addHandler(websocketHandler(), "/stomp")
            .setAllowedOrigins("*")
    }

    @Bean
    fun websocketHandler(): WebSocketHandler {
        return WebSocketHandler()
    }

}
```

*WebSocket Handler (TextWebSocketHandler)*

```
class WebSocketHandler : TextWebSocketHandler() {

    override fun handleTextMessage(
        session: WebSocketSession, message: TextMessage
    ) {
        println("Got message!\n->$message")
        super.handleTextMessage(session, message)
    }

}
```

*Security config*

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    fun springSecurityFilterChain(
        http: ServerHttpSecurity
    ): SecurityWebFilterChain {
        
        http
            .authorizeExchange { exchanges ->
                exchanges
                    .anyExchange().permitAll()

            }
            .csrf { it.disable() }
            .cors { it.disable() }
            .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())


        return http.build()
    }
}
```

*Client JS*

```
let socket = new WebSocket("wss://example.org/stomp");
```

*YAML config*

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    fun springSecurityFilterChain(
        http: ServerHttpSecurity
    ): SecurityWebFilterChain {
        
        http
            .authorizeExchange { exchanges ->
                exchanges
                    .anyExchange().permitAll()

            }
            .csrf { it.disable() }
            .cors { it.disable() }
            .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())


        return http.build()
    }
}
```

**The issue**

Server:

`HTTP GET "/stomp"`
`Completed 404 NOT_FOUND`

Client:

`main.js:1 WebSocket connection to 'wss://example.org/stomp' failed:`

There is also a regular @Controller present to serve the html with Thymeleaf in case that may be affecting request handling in the application.

Thank you for replies